# Как закрыть/удалить все потоки внутри потока, где они были созданы?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть поток, пусть будет поток-родитель:

```
        Thread Thread1 = new Thread(Void1); //
        Thread1 .Start();
```

Внутри родителя создано N потоков, пусть будут потоки-дети. После создания последнего потока внутри родителя я приостанавливаю поток-родитель. и теперь мне необходимо удалить всех "детей" не проверяя ничего, просто прибить их. Это возможно как-то сделать?

Comment: по хорошему, убивать поток нельзя. Нужно посылать им сообщение каким-то образом с просьбой закрыться.  А дальше все просто - поток родитель знает своих потомков и посылаем им нужно сообщение.

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Во-первых, у потока нет понятия «дочернего потока». Вы не можете найти потоки, созданные данным, разве что вы *сами* при создании нового потока запоминаете его в доступном месте.

Во-вторых, «убивать» потоки нельзя. Потоки обязаны сотрудничать, и сами завершаться в нужный момент. (Обычно для таких целей используют `CancellationToken`.)